# First 5 entries for a single user

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL. I need to get the dates for the first 5 transactions of every user on my DB.

```
Transaction - trans.id, trans.date, trans.cust_id, trans.value
Customer - cust.id, cust.created_at
```

I need to get the date of the first 5 transactions for all the customers.

Comment: in relational databases there is no such thing as first or last, unless you use ORDER BY something. and you can use LIMIT 5 to limit output to 5 rows only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT cust_id, date
FROM (
  SELECT cust_id,
         date,
         row_number() OVER (partition by cust_id
                            ORDER BY date, id ) rn
  FROM Transaction
) as alias
WHERE rn <= 5
ORDER BY 1,2
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cfd2e/4

Comment: What is your PostreSql version ? Windows fonctions (`over` clause) are suported beginning from verion 8.4.

Comment: Reworked it a few times and it worked. Thanks so much!